# newgrp - mygroup2 does not change environment (does not change default home directory)

Tags: bash, group

I am working on a CentOS release 6.9 linux distribution where my username is a member of two different groups: `mygroup1` and `mygroup2`. If I am currently logged into an interactive shell using my primary group (`mygroup1`) and try to switch into my secondary group (`mygroup2`) using the command `newgrp - mygroup2`, my group does change, but the behavior of the change directory (`cd ~`) command does not bring me back to the mygroup2 home directory. Any idea why?

```
ssh user@host.com
id -ng
# returns: mygroup1
cd ~
# returns: /home/mygroup1/user
newgrp - mygroup2
id -ng
# returns: mygroup2
cd ~
# returns: /home/mygroup1/user (same as above, not mygroup2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as a per-group home directory.
When you do `cd ~` you change to your user home directory which is usually set in `/etc/passwd` and does not depend on your group.

If you want to change your home, just do:

```
newgrp - mygroup2
HOME=/home/mygroup2/user
cd ~              # Will move you to $HOME
```

Comment: Great thanks! It never occurred to me to simply change the `HOME` variable.